# Daily Builds are no longer having an exectueable

Tags: blend-files

Blender doesn't start. For the last two downloads on daily builds, including today's Friday Aug 31, when I untar them the executable are not coming up executable but as shard libraries. anyone else experiencing this?

Linux OS Blender 2.79 64 bit

[Daily Builds](https://builder.blender.org/download/)

Comment: Which one are you downloading? In windows 2.79 from today im getting the .exe

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the Linux part. let me go edit that.. thanks for point that out.